# How to get X and Y in Chart1 using SQL to VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I saved my x and y in database
this how my database looks like:

```
 ID | Test_ID | Chart_X | Chart_Y'           |
 1  |    1    | 2,4,6,8 | 1.23,1.24,1.25,1.26|
```

to retrieve my data using vb.net here is my code:

```
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select *From OP_HydrostaticGRAPH2 where Test_ID = '" & nud_testno.Value & "'", conn)
 Dim myreader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
 Chart1.Series.Clear()
            Chart1.Series.Add("No1")
            Chart1.Series("No1").Color = Color.DodgerBlue
            Chart1.Series.Add("Temperature")
            Chart1.Series("Temperature").Color = Color.Red
            Chart1.Series("No1").ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
            Dim valueX As String
            Dim valueY As String
            Dim ii As Double
            myreader.Read()
            valueX = myreader.Item("Chart_X").ToString
            valueY = myreader.Item("Chart_Y").ToString
            Chart1.Series("No1").XValueMember = valueX
            Chart1.Series("No1").YValueMembers = valueY



            ' MsgBox(value)
            Dim str As String
            Dim strArr() As String
            str = valueX
            strArr = str.Split(",")


            Dim str1 As String
            Dim strArr1() As String
            str1 = valueY
            strArr1 = str1.Split(",")





            For i As Double = 0 To strArr.Count - 1
                Chart1.Series("No1").Points.AddXY(strArr(i), strArr1(i))

            Next

            conn.Close()
```

i'm using split for the "," to get numbers from the cell.
the problem is i can't get the right for loop for the X and Y Axis.
Any suggestion? or maybe you encountered this one before?

Comment: So much wrong with that.  Firstly, why would you store multiple values in a single field like that?  You're allowed multiple related tables in a database.  That's the whole point.

Comment: Secondly, you never actually extract anything out of `value` so why would you expect to get anything out of it?  This is the sort of code you end up with when to write it without any clue what it's supposed to do.  Exactly what logic is that code supposed to be implementing?  I suggest that you actually think about what steps are required to accomplish your goal rather than just the goal itself.  Write down those steps are test them manually.  Once they work, write code to implement those steps specifically.  If you have nothing to compare the code to, you can't tell when it makes no sense.

Comment: Where does `noOfPts` come from? Where are `X` and `Y` declared? Do you know what the `.AddXY()` method returns?

Comment: nOfPts is only a integer. the X and Y is for the chart but before that i am trying to put in on messagebox 1st to know if it's right or not.

Comment: Ok, `noOfPts` is an Integer. Where does the value of this Integer come from? Yes, `X` and `Y` are for the chart but where are they declared? And again, do you know what the `.AddXY()` method returns?

Comment: let me edit my question again and i think it's better than before